# How to set the cart subtotal by adding all item fields in Rect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to select several items and place them in the cart, but when I add more than one of them, a reset occurs in the array and in addition, the value is not being added correctly. What could be happening?

Update: Now I have another problem. When I add 2 items from the same pokemon to the list, the first pokemon is reset to 0 and the new pokemon is added twice to the list. How to solve this?

```
useEffect(() => {
  setValue(qtd.reduce((subtotal, item) => subtotal + item[2], 1));
}, [qtd]);

const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
const [qtd, setQtd] = useState([]);


function addItemToCart(qtd, index, pokemon) {
    console.log(qtd);
    const existingCartItem = qtd.find((item) => item[0] === index);
    if (existingCartItem) {
      const updatedCartItem = [
        existingCartItem[0],
        existingCartItem[1],
        existingCartItem[2] + (index + 1) * 4,
        existingCartItem[3] + 1,
      ];
      console.log(existingCartItem[0], index);
      qtd.splice(existingCartItem);
      console.log(updatedCartItem);
      setQtd([...qtd, updatedCartItem]);
    } else {
      setQtd([...qtd, [index, pokemon.pokemon.name, (index + 1) * 4, 1]]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setValue` inside useEffect.
i.e.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setValue(qtd.reduce((subtotal, item) => subtotal + item[2], 1));
}, [qtd]);
```

Comment: This part was solved, thanks. But the part of the array being reset when more than one item is inserted does not. What can it be?

Comment: Updated my question